# MySQL Connect via proxy in Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I am developing a client-server software, where the client connects to the database server as follows.

```
...
try
{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/agenda", "root", "LA_PASSWORD");
}catch....
...
```

Both applications are always on the same local network. The problem I have is when the local network uses a proxy, in this case the MySQL connection fails.

How I can make a connection with the Java programming language, a MySQL database when a proxy on the local network?.

Thanks for the help.
Greetings!

Comment: What do you mean "the local network uses a proxy" ? Do you mean an HTTP proxy? MySQL uses a binary protocol not HTTP. Is the connection being blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Yes, i mean an HTTP PROXY. Thanks.

Comment: @Lobo your proxy required authentification by user & psw ???

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using `socksProxyHost` and `socksProxyPort` system properties. Look [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) at chapter "2.4) SOCKS" and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html#socks). (The http.proxyHost will not work with JDBC.) Here is description of use proxy with JDBC (Oracle for example): [Connect outside internet Oracle Database from inside intranet through JDBC](http://adalili.com/2007/04/29/connect-outside-internet-oracle-database-from-inside-intranet-through-jdbc/). You may want to use properties: `socksProxySet, socksProxyPort, socksProxyHost, java.net.socks.username, java.net.socks.password, socksNonProxyHosts`. [Here is description how to set version, username, and password](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html#socks). And ofc **you need socks proxy, not HTTP**.

**If you only have HTTP proxy you can try to tunnel JDBC through HTTP.** There are few solutions. For example here is free solution http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlgateway/ and here commercial http://www.idssoftware.com/jdbcdrv.html

Comment: thanks for the answer. The provided solution will redirect  all the traffic over the socksProxyHost. In my case i have two DB connections. One should go through proxy and one is on the local network. Any suggestion how to handle this?

Comment: I just found the solution. It is property called socksNonProxyHosts where you may enlist all excluded hosts.