# Keeping getting a Communications link failure and don't know why

Tags: java, mysql

I did search here and found some useful code to connect to a MySql db using SSH tunneling.  I essentially copied the following code from another example, of course replacing it with my own credentials, but I keep getting the following error:

"com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: "

Code:

```
public void connect(){

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = null;
        Properties info = new Properties();

        info.put("proxy_host", "proxyhost.com");
        info.put("proxy_port", "22");
        info.put("proxy_user", "username");
        info.put("proxy_password", "password");
        info.put("user", "user_qa");
        info.put("password", "password");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://qa2-commerce-master:4417/commerce", info);

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    } catch (SQLException er) {
        er.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is all I have as I just want to get the connection to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I copied the code exactly from here:

[Connect to MySQL using JDBC driver through a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318702/connect-to-mysql-using-jdbc-driver-through-a-proxy)

Comment: could you add the stacktrace of the 'underlying exception' ?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that this code does SSH tunneling?

Comment: Honestly I've always connected to a DB directly without ever having to using tunneling, proxy, etc. so to answer your question I don't know, but I do know that when I searched this came up. So if I'm on the wrong path please direct me as to where I should go. I'm not looking for a direct answer, if provided great, but a path to head towards.

Comment: And also when I connect via IntlliJ, there's the option to configure using SSH And that's how I connect providing a proxy host, proxy username, proxy password, proxy port

Comment: Yes I will add the stack as soon as I get home