# Connect to MySQL Database through proxied IP address

Tags: java, mysql

I created a Science Fair project in Java, and I need to run it at school. However, my school, like most others, proxies their IP address. I need to connect to a MySQL database through a proxy. Help is very appreciated. :)

Comment: As it stands, this post would be considered off-topic for StackOverflow. Go check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and come back when you have a more specific programming-related question. That said, why can't you use a collocated database that's on the same school network (or same machine) instead of a remote one?

Comment: @admdrew Whoa, that is harsh. I would have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544635/mysql-connect-via-proxy-in-java

Comment: @blackpanther - not really harsh; 1) this post is not a question, and 2) the poster hasn't shown he/she did any research (like finding one of the many answers similar to your link)