# Connecting to a proxy user in MySQL 8 using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, proxy

I want to connect to MySQL through a proxy user, where I setup the database connection pool to authenticate using a proxy user and then make the connection retrieved from the pool authenticate using a proxied user, in Oracle it's done this way:

```
java.util.Properties userNameProp = new java.util.Properties();
userNameProp.setProperty(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_NAME, userName);
userNameProp.setProperty(OracleConnection.PROXY_USER_PASSWORD, password);

OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection) ds.getConnection();

conn.openProxySession(OracleConnection.PROXYTYPE_USER_NAME, userNameProp);
```

I can't seem to find any appropriate documentation for this.

Please note that this is not about network proxies, what I am asking is about is connecting via proxy users (a user acting as a proxy for other users to connect through it) this helps with having multi users access database while being able to maintain a connection pool.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544635/mysql-connect-via-proxy-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Connect via proxy in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544635/mysql-connect-via-proxy-in-java)

Comment: @Román no it doesn't, the ones you submitted are about network proxies, what I am asking is about proxy users (a user acting as a proxy for other users to connect through it) this helps with having multi users access database while being able to maintain a connection pool

Comment: Does MySQL even have such a function?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/proxy-users.html